# Why Informix dbexport is generating corrupt data?

Tags: informix

We are having a strange situation while trying to dbexport/dbimport an Informix database.
while importing the DB we got the error:
1213 - Character to numeric conversion error
I checked at which does does the import stops.

I edited the corresponding file (sed -n '1745813,1745815p' table.unl) and have seen data that look to be corrupt.

```
3.0]26.0]018102]0.0]20111001.0]0.0]77.38]20111012.0]978]04]0.0072]6.59]6.59]29.93]29.93]77.38]
3.0]26.0]018102]0.0]20111001.0]0.0]143.69]20111012.0]978]04]0.0144]6.59]6.59]48.79]48.79]143.69]
]0.000/]]-0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044]8\00\00\07Ú\00\00Õ²\00\00\07P27\00\00\07Ú\00\00i]-0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000999995+']-49999992%(000000000000000000.0]-989074999997704800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]-999992%(0000000000000000000000.0]]]Ú\00\00]*00000015056480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]-92%'9999)).'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]-;24944999992%(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]-81%-999994;2475200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]]-97704751999992%(00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0]
```

The first two lines are OK. The rest seems to be corrupt data.
I do not know how the data appears here since it does not appear in select statement.

I exported only the affected table and figured out that the same data is there.
I looked for a filter that matches all the rows, I used it in another export. This time the corrupt data is not there.

Any idea about what might be the reason behind this?

Best Regards
Arthur

Comment: Hi Arthur, your question is about dbexport right? why they generate the corrupt data... ?

Comment: Yes this is right, why does dbexport generate corrupt data

Comment: ok, first doubt, how exactly do you export the data showed at the question? UNLOAD? did you force the "]" delimiter?

Comment: Considering what you said , when filter the data don't appear , but when you export fully table the data appear, then your index is corrupted too. The index you can solve rebuilding it (disable/enable or drop/create), but this isn't solve your data corrupted. You can try check at more lower level the data corruption selecting ROWID of the row and then searching for this data with `oncheck -pp <db:tablename> <rowid>`

Comment: I forgot to write... the reason of corrupt data is any crash or involuntary shutdown of the engine. There is no way to recover the data corrupted, only with backup. What you can do is "remove" it from your export excluding the "bad" rowid from your unload.

Comment: Hello,
The export was done using the command dbexport. We exported the whole database.

Comment: Hello,
The export was done using the command dbexport. We exported the whole database.
I re-created the indexes as you suggested.
the oncheck command provided an output which was unclear for me.
As a solution I:
1. created a new table copy of the first one.
2. Insert into table 2 select * from table1 where (my filter which matched all rows)
3. recreated table indexes
4. renamed tables

Answer (score 0):

Arthur,

Trying answering the question, why the database is generating corrupted data.
You will need to investigate. 
The common causes is :

- Occur some crash at your OS/Hardware
- Occur some lack of energy
- Occur some crash at your database or they process are killed by some admin.
- After any of problems above, your FS become corrupt and probably at recovery (fsck) mess the database data.
  Probably you are working with a Journaling FS , which ext3,ext4,ntfs is...

If you don't know anything about any events like described before, you need to investigate into the online.log of our Informix database , looking for any start of the engine without a regular shutdown before. Look at your OS logs will help too to found for any involuntary restart of the OS (lack of energy or crash).

---

**Now about the solutions.**

1. Recover a backup
   Then you can export just the table corrupted and replace it at your dbexport.
   You can do this with [archecker](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/topic/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_224.htm). *(must be Informix version grater of 10.FC4)*
   This article maybe will help you if need : [Table Level Restore - Pretty Useful Stuff](http://www.informix-dba.com/2010/12/table-level-restore-pretty-useful-stuff.html)
2. Export your table just like your describe at the comments.
   But this will not recover the corrupt data, they just will "save" the "good" data and discard the "bad" data.

   > 1. created a new table copy of the first one.
   > 2. Insert into table 2 select * from table1 where (my filter which matched all rows)
   > 3. recreated table indexes
   > 4. renamed tables
3. Depending how is bad is the corrupted data sometimes you not able to export all "good" data at just one select, you need workaround the "bad" data , check this IBM article: 
   [Unloading around table corruption](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21300182)

---

**Ways to prevent this kind of problem or make easily any recover**

First, of course, there is no way to prevent any crash...
What you can do is try minimize the damage after any crash.

1. Do not use journal file systems!
   (at linux, use ext2 FS or RAW devices)
2. Enable KAIO (for RAW) or DIRECT_IO (of any FS) at Informix configuration.
   This will prevent the database to use the OS cache, making more secure the process of writing data at your disk. At some situations this can slower down or speed up your database, depends a lot of your hardware/storage.
3. Configure your backup to work and test/check it with some frequency.
   I recommend configure the backup of full database + logical logs backup.
4. Depending the version of the Informix and which license you have, you maybe have the rights to configure a cold RSS server ("cluster" secondary node) which will work as active-passive mode at different server and will reduce dramatically you chances to loose any data after any crash at the mainly server.
5. After any crash, run oncheck to detect the if occur some corruption : 
   [How to use oncheck to detect corruption](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21209842)

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for the comments. The dbexport/dbimport was done by DBA (Which I am not), We checked that the corrupt data are from 2011 which are no more needed for our customer.
I will check together with DBAs team how to rollback the data. As far as I know DBAs create daily backups that are stored on tapes.